# use 2 directories output in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i like to know if there's a way to use 2 directories output in delphi 7, to create the compiled project in 2 diferent folders Like :  **c:\test** ; **c:\testx**

i already tried the semicolon and didn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to make the compiler or IDE output the executable file to multiple directories. You'll have to copy it yourself as a post build action. You'll have to script that yourself since Delphi 7 does not have post build actions built in.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 script/batch file that uses the dcc32.exe

```
c:
cd  "\program files\borland\bds\4.0\bin\"
dcc32.exe c:\work\project -ec:\temp -uc:\work\extra
rem project is the name of your project  
rem note you can pass parameters to your script using %1 %2 etc etc upto 9 and use them
rem -e is where you want the output 
rem -i Include directories
rem -u is your search path to your libraries
pause
```